# PHP in block in Drupal not working

Tags: php, drupal

I have the following in a block where the text format is PHP code. For some reason the php is just stripped out when I view the page.

```
<a href="<?php print base_path(); ?>node/add/f2?edit[field_f2][und]=<?php print arg(2); ?>">New</a>
```

Comment: What order are your filters in. Check the text format and make sure php filter is first. Otherwise the html filter or somethign else may be stripping it out.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mismatched tag:

```
<a href="<?php print base_path(); ?>/node/add/f2?edit[field_f2][und]=<?php print arg(2); ?>"New</a>
```

Should be:

```
<a href="<?php print base_path(); ?>/node/add/f2?edit[field_f2][und]=<?php print arg(2); ?>">New</a>
```

Notice the extra `>` before the "New"

Answer (score 1):

Besides enabling the 'PHP Filter' module and setting the correct permissions, you also need to edit the format type here:

```
/admin/config/content/formats/php_code
```

Tick the 'Roles' you want to have access, and tick the 'PHP evaluator' filter option.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `;` missing after `print base_path()`.
It should be `print base_path();`

Comment: This isn't required in this case. In PHP, a closing tag `?>` implies a semi-colon. I agree it's good practice to include one - but that shouldn't be causing an issue.

Comment: Ive added the ; but it still isnt working. Ive updated my question.

Comment: @ColinMorelli Didn't knew that, Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ColinMorelli Should I delete this answer ?

Comment: @Ankit It's up to you, but I don't think you need to. I think the answer and comment might teach someone else something new as well. Go ahead and leave it.